# How can micro services do with Docker Compose and swarm mode?

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, microservices, docker-swarm-mode

Need help with this MCQ. Please explain the answer if possible

How can microservices do with Docker Compose and swarm mode?

A. Construct and define multi container application

B. Provide analysis reports of container orchestration performance

C. Collect data on speed and efficiency and recommend alterations

D. None of the options

Comment: Something makes me feel that the question should be *What* rather than *How*.

Comment: I know..I also feel it odd

Answer (score 0):

Answer: None of the given options (Assuming the question is about *What* rather than *How*)

Reason:

All the options given in *A-C* are handled by a container-orchestration platform, be it Kubernetes, Docker Swarm Azure container service or any other platform of your choice. Microservice applications can at most spin up a docker container but they can't really decide by themselves stuffs like, how many containers to spin up, when to stop some of them etc. cause the main aim of the application is not manage the container but to address business needs.